# Abaqus subroutine UVARM -1.#IND in Windows & -nan in Centos 6.6

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have written subroutine `UVARM` for Abaqus. The program is running but displaying results

```
    -1.#IND
```

in Windows and

```
    -nan
```

in Centos 6.6.

Below is the partial script:

I am unable to solve it but it seems to me variable `INVT` becoming `sqrt(-1)` in below code. How can I run this by extracting only real part? Below I think it is ending up with `INVT = some Real number + SQRT(-Some number)`. How can I resolve this ?

```
C     Stress tensor:
      CALL GETVRM('S',ARRAY,JARRAY,FLGRAY,JRCD,JMAC,JMATYP,
     1 MATLAYO,LACCFLA)
      JERROR = JERROR + JRCD
      SIGMA11 = ARRAY(1)
      SIGMA22 = ARRAY(2)
      SIGMA33 = ARRAY(3)
      SIGMA12 = ARRAY(4)
      SIGMA13 = ARRAY(5)
      SIGMA23 = ARRAY(6)
C     REARRANGE THE STRESS VECTOR ***** 

C     MCT DECOMPOSITION
      SIGMAM=MATMUL(MATQM,SIGMAC)
      INVT=(SIGMAM(2,1)+SIGMAM(3,1)+
     1 SQRT((SIGMAM(2,1)+SIGMAM(3,1))**2-
     2 4*(SIGMAM(2,1)*SIGMAM(3,1)+SIGMAM(4,1)**2)))/2
      INVS1=SIGMAM(6,1)**2+SIGMAM(5,1)**2
      INVS2=0.25*(SIGMAM(2,1)-SIGMAM(3,1))**2+SIGMAM(4,1)**2

C     MACAULAY BRACKETS 
      IF (INVT.LT.0) THEN
          INVT=0.0
      END IF

      SIGMAEFFT=SQRT((BT/BS1)*INVT**2+INVS1+(BS2/BS1)*INVS2)

      SIGMAEFFL=SIGMAM(1,1)

C     MACAULAY BRACKETS 
      IF (SIGMAEFFL.LT.0) THEN
          SIGMAEFFL=0.0
      END IF
```

Comment: Please avoid things like *plz* here.

Comment: Declare your variables and make the complex, if you want to use complex arithmetic. Then convert it back to real.

Comment: Thanks haraldkl, this may be too basic but can you show in my case.